# Protecting thread-local storage of a thread from other threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-local-storage

Thread-local storage is a method to [reduce synchronization](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-thread-local-storage-to-reduce-synchronization) overhead in multi-threaded applications where data is not shared between threads. That requires a protection mechanism around certain thread-local memory locations (like TLS and stack) in order that only a single one of the threads may access that memory.  Since all threads within a process share the same virtual address space, how is thread-local storage and stack of a thread is protected from other threads of the same process?

I guess OS should provide such a protection mechanism, and if so, how? ... The whole concept of thread-local storage is to reduce overhead, so involving OS means adding overhead. Is there a runtime library or hardware support? or maybe is not protected at all and is left to the programmer...

Comment: Well, stack/local/auto storage vars don't require synchro overhead either when data is not shared between threads.

Comment: Did I say they need sync?!

Comment: No, but you implied that TLS data was defined by no requiring synchro when data is not  shared between threads.  I pointed out that this was too narrow a description.

Comment: It might be possible to enable some form of per-thread memory protection using the new '[SGX](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx)' instructions in recent Intel CPUs. [Hardware support is currently very sparse](https://github.com/ayeks/SGX-hardware) though. Otherwise, you need to go to great lengths to achieve this effect — every system-call accounted for, every other thread suspended while TLS memory pages are writable, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that a programmer could access the thread local storage space of another thread **within the same process**. It wouldn't be trivial since the programmer would have to either access the memory directly or use some undocumented APIs but it could theoretically be done. But, why would he (or she)?! The whole premise of the TLS is to make it easy for programmers to store data in a place that is not shared with other threads within the process.

The fact that the thread local storage is managed by the OS means that the actual location of the thread local storage in the process's memory is not advertised directly. Reading and writing to the TLS is "managed" by the operating system with relatively low overhead (a function call) by suppling a simple Get/Set api. The protection here is mostly convenience by making it difficult for somebody to accidentally access data that belongs (is also accessed) by a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. A couple of questions. 1. If reading/writing from/to TLS is managed by sys calls, I would consider it costly. Or maybe you mean it is done through user-level function calls with no OS involvement?
2. What about stacks? Stacks are private to each thread. Let's say I am a bad programmer and somehow mess up with another thread's stack. Then does OS stop me? I guess not.

Comment: To me, TLS vars are not much better than global vars for multiple threads.

Comment: Why would he or she? A dozen reasons. For example, say an object needs to log something and the logger has its own thread. Say a container needs to be sorted, and the sorting logic uses multiple threads. The whole point of threads is that objects belong to the process so that you generally don't have to worry about which thread is doing something.

Comment: @aminfar If you do bad things in a process, bad things will happen. If two things need to be isolated from each other, don't put them in the same process. Threads must cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require a protection mechanism. In fact, a protection mechanism would just make things much more difficult. For example, say a thread wants to sort one of its objects, so it passes it to a sorting method. What happens if that sorting method uses multiple threads "under the hood" to do the sorting?

So your question is based on an entirely false premise. Such a protection mechanism would mean that every method that operated on an object would have to declare whether it was safe to operate on thread-specific data or not, which would be a nightmare.